# Illegal instance declaration for ‘Show DecV’

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a Parser for an extension of the While Language, called Proc, that takes input such as `x:=1` and returns `Ass "x" (N 1)`. My code so far is below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
module Attempt where
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.String
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Prelude hiding (Num)
import qualified Prelude (Num)
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

-- S ::= x:=a
--    | skip
--    | S1 ; S2
--    | if b then S1 else S2
--    | while b do S
--    | begin Dv Dv S end
--    | call p
-- Dv ::= var x := a ; DV | ε
-- Dp ::= proc p is S ; DP | ε

type Num   = Integer
type Var   = String
type Pname = String
type DecV  = [(Var,Aexp)]
type DecP  = [(Pname,Stm)]

--Parser

--A few preliminaries that import modules and language features before
--the full parser is defined.

cr :: Parser [Char]
cr = many (oneOf "\r\n")

tok :: String -> Parser String
tok t = string t <* whitespace

whitespace :: Parser ()
whitespace = many (oneOf " \t") *> pure ()

--Now each of the production rules in the grammar will be considered and
--translated into a corresponding datatype and parser.

-- a ::= | n | x | a1 + a2 | a1 * a2 | a1 - a2

data Aexp = N Num
          | V Var
          | Mult Aexp Aexp
          | Add Aexp Aexp
          | Sub Aexp Aexp

aexp :: Parser Aexp
aexp =  N     <$> num
    <|> V     <$> var
    <|> Mult  <$> aexp <* tok "*" <*> aexp
    <|> Add   <$> aexp <* tok "+" <*> aexp
    <|> Sub   <$> aexp <* tok "-" <*> aexp

-- b ::= true | false | a1 = a2 | a1 =< a2 | !b | b1 & b2

data Bexp = TRUE
          | FALSE
          | Neg Bexp
          | And Bexp Bexp
          | Le Aexp Aexp
          | Eq Aexp Aexp

bexp :: Parser Bexp
bexp = TRUE   <$ tok "TRUE"
   <|> FALSE  <$ tok "FALSE"
   <|> Neg    <$ tok "!" <*> bexp
   <|> And    <$> bexp <* tok "&" <*> bexp
   <|> Le     <$> aexp <* tok "=<" <*> aexp
   <|> Eq     <$> aexp <* tok "=" <*> aexp

-- S ::= x:=a
--    | skip
--    | S1 ; S2
--    | if b then S1 else S2
--    | while b do S
--    | begin Dv Dp S end
--    | call p

data Stm = Skip
          | Ass Var Aexp
          | Comp Stm Stm
          | If Bexp Stm Stm
          | While Bexp Stm
          | Block DecV DecP Stm
          | Call Pname

stm :: Parser Stm
stm = Skip    <$ tok "Skip"
  <|> Ass     <$ tok "Ass" <*> var <* tok ":=" <*> aexp
  <|> Comp    <$ tok "Comp" <*> stm <* tok ";" <*> stm
  <|> If      <$ tok "If" <*> bexp <* tok "then" <*> stm <* tok "else" <*> stm
  <|> While   <$ tok "While" <*> bexp <* tok "do" <*> stm
  <|> Block   <$ tok "Block" <* tok "begin" <*> decv <*> decp <*> stm <* tok "end"
  <|> Call    <$ tok "Call" <*> pname

-- Dv ::= var x := a ; DV | ε

decv :: Parser DecV
decv = many ((,) <$> var <* tok ":=" <*> aexp <* tok ";")

-- Dp ::= proc p is S ; DP | ε

decp :: Parser DecP
decp = many ((,) <$> pname <* tok "is" <*> stm <* tok ";")

num :: Parser Num
num = (some (oneOf ['0' .. '9']) >>= return . read) <* whitespace

var :: Parser Var
var = (some (oneOf ['A' .. 'Z'])) <* whitespace

pname :: Parser Pname
pname = tok "\"" *> some (noneOf ("\n\r\"")) <* tok "\""

whileParser :: Parser Stm
whileParser = whitespace >> stm

parseFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
parseFile filePath = do
  file <- readFile filePath
  putStrLn $ case parse whileParser filePath file of
    Left err          -> parseErrorPretty err
    Right whileParser -> pretty whileParser


--Pretty Printing
---------------

--The instances below allow values to be inspected in the terminal.
--The default instance that is derived shows all the constructor names.

deriving instance Show Aexp
deriving instance Show Bexp
deriving instance Show Stm
deriving instance Show DecV

--The pretty-printed output gives a version that should be acceptable
--Proc.

class Pretty a where
  pretty :: a -> String

instance Pretty Aexp where
  pretty (N num)            = show num
  pretty (V var)            = show var
  pretty (Mult aexp1 aexp2) = "Mult " ++ pretty aexp1 ++ " " ++ pretty aexp2
  pretty (Add aexp1 aexp2)  = "Add " ++ pretty aexp1 ++ " " ++ pretty aexp2
  pretty (Sub aexp1 aexp2)  = "Sub " ++ pretty aexp1 ++ " " ++ pretty aexp2

instance Pretty Bexp where
  pretty (TRUE)             = show True
  pretty (FALSE)            = show False
  pretty (Neg bexp)         = "!" ++ pretty bexp
  pretty (And bexp1 bexp2)  = pretty bexp1 ++ " & " ++ pretty bexp2
  pretty (Le aexp1 aexp2)   = pretty aexp1 ++ " =< " ++ pretty aexp2
  pretty (Eq aexp1 aexp2)   = pretty aexp1 ++ " = " ++ pretty aexp2

instance Pretty Stm where
  pretty (Skip)               = "Skip "
  pretty (Ass var aexp)       = "Ass " ++ var ++ " := " ++ pretty aexp
  pretty (Comp stm1 stm2)     = "Comp " ++ pretty stm1 ++ pretty stm2
  pretty (If bexp stm1 stm2)  = "If " ++ pretty bexp ++ " " ++ pretty stm1 ++ " " ++ pretty stm2
  pretty (While bexp stm)     = "While " ++ pretty bexp ++ " " ++ pretty stm
  pretty (Block decv decp stm)= "Block " ++ pretty decv ++ " " ++ pretty decp ++ " " ++ pretty stm
  pretty (Call pname)         = "Call " ++ pretty pname

wrap :: Char -> String
wrap c = [c]
```

But when I try and compile it, I'm receiving the below error from my line `deriving instance Show DecV`:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Show DecV’
  (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
   where T is not a synonym.
   Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the stand-alone deriving instance for ‘Show DecV’
```

**edit**:

Removed `deriving` from the instances of Stm, DecV and DecP fixed that issue, also changed `pretty` to `show` in Pretty Block. I'm now getting an error:

```
Overlapping instances for Show DecP arising from a use of ‘show’
Matching instances:
  instance Show a => Show [a] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
  instance Show DecP -- Defined at 2ndattempt.hs:143:10
In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘show decp’
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
  ‘show decp ++ " " ++ pretty stm’
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely
  ‘" " ++ show decp ++ " " ++ pretty stm’
```

current code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
module Attempt where
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.String
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Prelude hiding (Num)
import qualified Prelude (Num)
import System.IO
import Control.Monad

-- S ::= x:=a
--    | skip
--    | S1 ; S2
--    | if b then S1 else S2
--    | while b do S
--    | begin Dv Dv S end
--    | call p
-- Dv ::= var x := a ; DV | ε
-- Dp ::= proc p is S ; DP | ε

type Num   = Integer
type Var   = String
type Pname = String
type DecV  = [(Var,Aexp)]
type DecP  = [(Pname,Stm)]

--Parser

--A few preliminaries that import modules and language features before
--the full parser is defined.

cr :: Parser [Char]
cr = many (oneOf "\r\n")

tok :: String -> Parser String
tok t = string t <* whitespace

whitespace :: Parser ()
whitespace = many (oneOf " \t") *> pure ()

--Now each of the production rules in the grammar will be considered and
--translated into a corresponding datatype and parser.

-- a ::= | n | x | a1 + a2 | a1 * a2 | a1 - a2

data Aexp = N Num
          | V Var
          | Mult Aexp Aexp
          | Add Aexp Aexp
          | Sub Aexp Aexp

aexp :: Parser Aexp
aexp =  N     <$> num
    <|> V     <$> var
    <|> Mult  <$> aexp <* tok "*" <*> aexp
    <|> Add   <$> aexp <* tok "+" <*> aexp
    <|> Sub   <$> aexp <* tok "-" <*> aexp

-- b ::= true | false | a1 = a2 | a1 =< a2 | !b | b1 & b2

data Bexp = TRUE
          | FALSE
          | Neg Bexp
          | And Bexp Bexp
          | Le Aexp Aexp
          | Eq Aexp Aexp

bexp :: Parser Bexp
bexp = TRUE   <$ tok "TRUE"
   <|> FALSE  <$ tok "FALSE"
   <|> Neg    <$ tok "!" <*> bexp
   <|> And    <$> bexp <* tok "&" <*> bexp
   <|> Le     <$> aexp <* tok "=<" <*> aexp
   <|> Eq     <$> aexp <* tok "=" <*> aexp

-- S ::= x:=a
--    | skip
--    | S1 ; S2
--    | if b then S1 else S2
--    | while b do S
--    | begin Dv Dp S end
--    | call p

data Stm = Skip
          | Ass Var Aexp
          | Comp Stm Stm
          | If Bexp Stm Stm
          | While Bexp Stm
          | Block DecV DecP Stm
          | Call Pname

stm :: Parser Stm
stm = Skip    <$ tok "Skip"
  <|> Ass     <$ tok "Ass" <*> var <* tok ":=" <*> aexp
  <|> Comp    <$ tok "Comp" <*> stm <* tok ";" <*> stm
  <|> If      <$ tok "If" <*> bexp <* tok "then" <*> stm <* tok "else" <*> stm
  <|> While   <$ tok "While" <*> bexp <* tok "do" <*> stm
  <|> Block   <$ tok "Block" <* tok "begin" <*> decv <*> decp <*> stm <* tok "end"
  <|> Call    <$ tok "Call" <*> pname

-- Dv ::= var x := a ; DV | ε

decv :: Parser DecV
decv = many ((,) <$> var <* tok ":=" <*> aexp <* tok ";")

-- Dp ::= proc p is S ; DP | ε

decp :: Parser DecP
decp = many ((,) <$> pname <* tok "is" <*> stm <* tok ";")

num :: Parser Num
num = (some (oneOf ['0' .. '9']) >>= return . read) <* whitespace

var :: Parser Var
var = (some (oneOf ['A' .. 'Z'])) <* whitespace

pname :: Parser Pname
pname = tok "\"" *> some (noneOf ("\n\r\"")) <* tok "\""

whileParser :: Parser Stm
whileParser = whitespace >> stm

parseFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
parseFile filePath = do
  file <- readFile filePath
  putStrLn $ case parse whileParser filePath file of
    Left err          -> parseErrorPretty err
    Right whileParser -> pretty whileParser


--Pretty Printing
---------------

--The instances below allow values to be inspected in the terminal.
--The default instance that is derived shows all the constructor names.

deriving instance Show Aexp
deriving instance Show Bexp
instance Show Stm
instance Show DecV
instance Show DecP

--The pretty-printed output gives a version that should be acceptable
--Proc.

class Pretty a where
  pretty :: a -> String

instance Pretty Aexp where
  pretty (N num)            = show num
  pretty (V var)            = show var
  pretty (Mult aexp1 aexp2) = "Mult " ++ pretty aexp1 ++ " " ++ pretty aexp2
  pretty (Add aexp1 aexp2)  = "Add " ++ pretty aexp1 ++ " " ++ pretty aexp2
  pretty (Sub aexp1 aexp2)  = "Sub " ++ pretty aexp1 ++ " " ++ pretty aexp2

instance Pretty Bexp where
  pretty (TRUE)             = show True
  pretty (FALSE)            = show False
  pretty (Neg bexp)         = "!" ++ pretty bexp
  pretty (And bexp1 bexp2)  = pretty bexp1 ++ " & " ++ pretty bexp2
  pretty (Le aexp1 aexp2)   = pretty aexp1 ++ " =< " ++ pretty aexp2
  pretty (Eq aexp1 aexp2)   = pretty aexp1 ++ " = " ++ pretty aexp2

instance Pretty Stm where
  pretty (Skip)               = "Skip "
  pretty (Ass var aexp)       = "Ass " ++ var ++ " := " ++ pretty aexp
  pretty (Comp stm1 stm2)     = "Comp " ++ pretty stm1 ++ pretty stm2
  pretty (If bexp stm1 stm2)  = "If " ++ pretty bexp ++ " " ++ pretty stm1 ++ " " ++ pretty stm2
  pretty (While bexp stm)     = "While " ++ pretty bexp ++ " " ++ pretty stm
  pretty (Block decv decp stm)= "Block " ++ show decv ++ " " ++ show decp ++ " " ++ pretty stm
  pretty (Call pname)         = "Call " ++ pname

wrap :: Char -> String
wrap c = [c]
```

Comment: It means that "DecV" is not a full-fledged type but is just a Type Synonym (denoted by keyword 'type'). You can't instantiate on type synonyms in vanilla Haskell. The suggestion from compiler to use TypeSynonymInstances language extension will allow you to make type synonyms Instances of type classes.

Comment: However in your code you don't need to derive instance of Show for DecV as [(a,b)] is instance of show for all types a and b that are instances of Show. Just remove the "deriving" clause for this synonym and it should work. I would also advice to stick the deriving clauses to the corresponding data type definitions, as it would keep all the important for specific types bits of code in one place and would allow you to remove the unnecessary extension in code.

Comment: @Antisthenes thanks very much, removing the `deriving` works but now I have a `Couldn't match type ‘(Var, Aexp)’ with ‘Char’` error in my `pretty (Block decv decp stm) line`

Comment: It's because [(Var, Aexp)] is not instance of Pretty class. The easiest way to fix this is to replace pretty with show where it's not applicable, but if you want to have some specific form of output string then you may instantiate these types.

Comment: @Antisthenes Ive replaced pretty with show but now get overlapping instances error

Comment: When i wrote about removing deriving i meant removing all these instances as they aren't necessary and it would help you avoid "type synonym instances" extension. There are overlapping instances because, as i've written already in previus comments, list of tuples of two types that are instances of Show is already instance of Show. Besides if you would want to have instance of class without defining method you would have to  derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a type synonym

```
type Foo = [Int]
```

`Int` and `[Int]` are both instances of `Show` already. So when you say

```
instance Show Foo
```

you create a new instance of `Show` for the `[Int]`. So now when you have

```
x :: Foo
show x
```

the poor compiler doesn't know which version of `show` to call. So it complains. This is an "overlapping instance" because the two instances cover at least some of the same types.

Remove the instances for your type synonyms, but leave them for your `data` types.